# flex: how to prevent PASTE (ctrl+V) in a flex3 textinput?

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

Hello
I need to disable pasting text in a textinout (flex3) : CTRL+V 
Any idea ?

reagrds

Answer (score 5):

This only block pasting more than one letter, but it does work for most purposes:

```
<mx:TextInput textInput="if (event.text.length > 1) event.preventDefault()"/>
```

and for spark:

```
<s:TextInput
   change="if (event.operation is PasteOperation) 
   (event.target as SkinnableTextBase).text = '' "
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you can't with the TextInput :

> TextField objects do not dispatch
>   clear, copy, cut, paste, or selectAll
>   events. TextField objects always
>   include Cut, Copy, Paste, Clear, and
>   Select All commands in the context
>   menu. You cannot remove these commands
>   from the context menu for TextField
>   objects. For TextField objects,
>   selecting these commands (or their
>   keyboard equivalents) does not
>   generate clear, copy, cut, paste, or
>   selectAll events. However, other
>   classes that extend the
>   InteractiveObject class, including
>   components built using the Flash Text
>   Engine (FTE), will dispatch these
>   events in response to user actions
>   such as keyboard shortcuts and context
>   menus.

There is a workaround here :
[How do you stop Copy/Paste in a flash form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/485072/how-do-you-stop-copy-paste-in-a-flash-form)

Comment: Neither mx nor spark TextInput inherit from TextField, so I don't think that comment applies to them.